# Modify CSV Parser to work with TSV files C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have this code for parsing a CSV file.

```
var query = from line in File.ReadAllLines("E:/test/sales/" + filename)
                        let customerRecord = line.Split(',')
                        select new FTPSalesDetails
                        {
                            retailerName = "Example",
                        };

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                //sales details table
                ItemSale ts = new ItemSale
                {
                    RetailerID = GetRetailerID(item.retailerName)  
                };
            }
```

Obviously there will be more data in the above code, I am just awaiting the test information file details/structure.

In the mean time I thought I'd ask if this could me modified to parse TSV files?

All help is appreciated,

thanks :)

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: Unless you need advanced features like quote or escape characters its easier to write it yourself than getting some third party code, checking its license, reviewing its quality,...

Comment: @CodeInChaos: If the OP is struggling with relatively simple stuff like switching a comma delimiter for a tab then I suspect that third-party code would be the simpler, safer option, especially when it's a well-known, well-tested project like this one, and distributed under a permissive license (MIT, in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming tsv is tab separated value, you can use

```
line.Split('\t')
```

if you are using .NET 4.0, i would recommend that u use [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) for large files in order to use LINQ and not to load all the lines in memory at once.

Comment: Thanks for that Mubashir. I will mark your answer as correct once the time limit is up. For File.ReadLines do you just recommend using a loop then?

Comment: definitely as it returns IEnumerable<string>