# How to work with a large TSV file

Tags: excel, dataset, data-visualization, csv, tableau-api

I have a 5GB+ TSV file. I need to visualize the data it contains, but Excel cannot open the file (apparently is too big). Tableau does not work with TSV files and neither does Access. I tried with 010 Editor, which can open the file but no export it in a useful format. How can I open/export/transform it?

Answer (score 4):

Agree with Dan, such data should be loaded into database and run queries on it. One handy tool to do that is [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). You can import csv, tsv files into this as tables and run SQL queries on it. It uses sqlite underline and supports most of the SQL functions. Works on Mac and Windows as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this problem before. The trouble is that in order to open a file in Excel, you usually have to load the entire file into memory. This is fine when the file is 50 or 500k, but when it's 5GB, the system cannot load it into memory.

In order to work with that much data, you really need to load it into a database and run queries on it. Databases are optimized to work with large quantities of data (even way in excess of 5GB).

The tricky part will be loading this data into a database. You need a program which can parse your file (read line by line) and insert each TSV value into the appropriate database column. Writing an app to do this yourself may be best. If you're a windows person, you can use C# (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-2010-express) and MSSQL Express (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062). Here's a helpful resource for parsing ([Modify CSV Parser to work with TSV files C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067979/modify-csv-parser-to-work-with-tsv-files-c-sharp)). Here's a resource for inserting rows into MSSQL ([How to insert data into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241084/how-to-insert-data-into-sql-server))